# NativeScript + angular 2 : Use of back button click listener

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am developing cross platform mobile application using **NativeScript + Angular 2**.

I want to handle back button click of the current View, i.e. when user clicks on back button in android device, i want to perform an action like killing / removing the current view from the stack.

**For ex:** In android platform (Native Development) we can use `finish()` method of the activity for removing it from the stack. We can handle onBackPressed() like -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    finish();  //Removes current Activity from stack
}
```

So is there any way to handle `onBackPressed()` and `finish()` method in **NativeScript + angular 2**? I googled a lot but didn't find any solution and also tried **`Frame.goBack()`** in NativeScript + Angular 2, but didn't worked for me. It works great in NativeScript + JavaScript.

**UPDATE**

I want to remove view permanently from the stack as it is not needed any more in application. It should display first time when app install.

**For ex :**

Like **Login Screen**

1) When app installs then Login screen should display and on next launch of the application, App will automatically skip the Login Screen and move to the Home Screen(This is working fine)

2) But the problem is when i press back button from Home Screen then app navigates to Login screen every time because Login screen still present in STACK. So that's why i want to remove login screen permanently from stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to implement going back is to inject **Location** and use the method **back()**

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private location: Location) { }

    public goBack() {
        this.location.back();
    }
}
```

At this point when the user goes back, you shouldn't worry about explicitly destroying the view as there is no mobile option for going "forward"

Comment: There is one update in your code, injection of the Location class should be imported from '@angular/common' not from '@angular/router-deprecated'. I am updating it in your code :) Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nick, I have another question regarding LOGIN Screen. Please check my UPDATE in the same question and let me know if there is any way. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey Onkar the functionality you are seeking is not implemented at this very moment but its discussed here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/309 and here : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/284 and there you can track its development from the source itself :)